# Swift map function variability

Tags: ios, swift

I've got this properly working map function:

```
let movingImages = (1...71).map { UIImage(named: "Animation.\($0)")! }
```

Except there is no Animation.1 file - it's Animation.01

Rather than renaming the files, how can I code it to add a 0 to the numbers before 10?

**Edit:** this question differs from others because the answer provided elsewhere about adding a 0 to single digit number in Swift needs additional context in order to be used within a mapping that needs to return a value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `String(format: ...)` with the `%02d` for this:

```
let movingImages = (1...71).map {  index -> UIImage? in
     let imageNumber = String(format: "%02d", index) 
     return UIImage(named: "Animation.\(imageNumber)")!
}
```

Also, on the side note, avoid using force unwrapping (`!`).

A more safe way:

**Swift 4:**

```
let movingImages = (1...71).flatMap { index -> UIImage? in
     let imageNumber = String(format: "%02d", index) 
     return UIImage(named: "Animation.\(imageNumber)")
}
```

**Swift 4.1:**

```
let movingImages = (1...71).compactMap { index -> UIImage? in
     let imageNumber = String(format: "%02d", index) 
     return UIImage(named: "Animation.\(imageNumber)")
}
```

Comment: Forced unwrapping of the images is actually desired here since it will cause a crash letting the developer know very early in development that there is a missing image file. The use of `flatMap/compactMap` will hide the fact that one or more of the images may be missing.